# Fast Copy Array in Array VB6.0

Tags: arrays, vb6, copy

i have an array that i want to copy in two-dimensional (like jagged)
this is my code :

```
Dim cB(1000000) As Double
Dim buffer(50, 1000000) As Double

For I = 1 To 1000000
    cB(I) = CInt(Int((50 * Rnd()) + 1))
Next
```

I can use a for to copy cB to buffer. like this code :

```
For I = 1 To 10

   For j = 1 To 1000000
        buffer(I, j) = cb(j)
   Next

Next
```

but i want to know is there any faster method to do this?
in vb.net or C# i could use List.
is there some thing like this in vb6.0?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe don't copy the array at all?

```
Function AccessMyArray(arr, i, j)
    ' TODO: add range check using LBound() / UBound()
    AccessMyArray = arr(i * 1024 + j)
End Function
```

Comment: this is not my problem. i want copy array to multi-dimensional as fast as posible.

Comment: I get that, but why do you want to change the array structure so trivially without any real need? Your question seems to focus on turning a one-dimensional array into a uniformly nested array (i.e. one row of 10240 items into ten rows of 1024 items, that's basically a no-op).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a generic List object in VB6, but there is a Dictionary object which is roughly equivalent to the generic Dictionary object in .Net.  Set a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and you'll find it.